# Blog Post Title apearing twice

Tags: title, blog-page

I can seem to find what is wrong. Here is the problem http://www.cookouvagia.com/blog/

Title of the latest recipe appears twice.

Any advice would be great!

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please post the code being used to output the blog.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the archive description automitically generated by genesis.

Look in your archive page template and remove(*) something like `do_action('before_archive_posts');`

(*) You can update your question with your archive template code. As I don't use this theme, I don't know the right name, and more details you could remove this action easily in the functions.php file without editiong your template.